# What does the LogCat Error Actually Mean?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-logcat

[image]

I have created an App With Navigation Drawer and am using fragments. I have this particular fragment which uses a ListView and the List is Populated using JSON . When I try to open the particular fragment , the App Crashes and this is the LogCat result. Please Help.

Comment: You need to show your java file and also xml file.

Comment: Java Code - http://pastebin.com/2PgD0zAV
XML -   http://pastebin.com/wzsj8uhn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml file you need to change for `ListView` ID from

```
 android:id="@+id/events"
```

to

```
 android:id="@+id/android:list"
```

UPDATE:

You have just declared your `ProgressDialog` variable named `pDialog` not initialize So initialize it in `onPreExecute()` method like

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
pDialog.setMessage("Loading Events...");
pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
pDialog.setCancelable(true);
pDialog.show();
```

Comment: @Bhargav You'r Wel come. Glad to help you!!

Answer (score 0):

My quess..You are using a ListFragment derived class with an xml file that has a view in it with the id android.R.id.list. That view is not a ListView.

When you use a listfragment derived fragment you do not need an xml layout file, but if you create one the listview in it has to have the id android.R.id.list

Comment: So I can go ahead and delete the XML Layout file and remove the link ?

Comment: If you want to use just a listview, however you need to reference the listview using getListView() and set the adapter using setListAdapter. You could also keep the xml file, it does not matter just make sure the listview has the correct id (and no other view has it).